# Expand a cell to full screen when selected inside UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble getting a UICollectionViewCell to expand to the full screen width and height when selected in didSelectItemAt. The first cell expands perfectly fine but the other cells after animate off screen when selected. It seems as if the X and Y coordinates are not at 0 when scrolling the cells inside a CollectionView. Trying to get this working in Swift. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
struct itemStruct
  {
    // Set your values here...
    internal let itemWidth: CGFloat = 200
    internal let itemHeight: CGFloat = 300
    internal let minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat = 30
    internal let animationDuration: Double = 0.2
    internal let transformScale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
  }

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
    {
     private let options = itemStruct()
     private var cv: UICollectionView!
     private var isfirstTimeTransform: Bool = true

  override func viewDidLoad()
   {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.initViews()
   }

  // MARK: - UI
 private func initViews()
   {
    // Collection View Layout
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: options.itemWidth, height: options.itemHeight)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = options.minimumInteritemSpacing

    let horizontalInset: CGFloat  = (self.view.frame.size.width - options.itemWidth) / 2
    let verticalInset: CGFloat = (self.view.frame.size.height - options.itemHeight) / 2
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(verticalInset, horizontalInset, verticalInset, horizontalInset)

    // Collection View
    cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    cv.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(cv)
}

// MARK: UICollectionView Data Source
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 10
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    if indexPath.row == 0 && isfirstTimeTransform
    {
        isfirstTimeTransform = false
    }
    else
    {
        cell.transform = options.transformScale
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = cv.cellForItem(at: indexPath)  // or whatever you collection view cell class name is.

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.cv)
        collectionView.bringSubview(toFront: item!)
        item?.frame.origin = self.view.frame.origin   /// this view origin will be at the top of the scroll content, you'll have to figure this out
        item?.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width
        item?.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.height
    })
}


func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)
{
    let pageWidth: CGFloat = options.itemWidth + options.minimumInteritemSpacing; // width + space
    let currentOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    let targetOffset: CGFloat = targetContentOffset.pointee.x;
    var newTargetOffset: CGFloat = 0

    if targetOffset > currentOffset
    {
        newTargetOffset = ceil(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth
    }
    else
    {
        newTargetOffset = floor(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth
    }

    if newTargetOffset < 0
    {
        newTargetOffset = 0
    }
    else if newTargetOffset > scrollView.contentSize.width
    {
        newTargetOffset = scrollView.contentSize.width
    }

    targetContentOffset.pointee.x = currentOffset
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: newTargetOffset, y: 0), animated: true)

    var index = Int(newTargetOffset / pageWidth)
    if index == 0
    {
        // If first index
        var cell = self.cv.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
        UIView.animate(withDuration: options.animationDuration, animations: {
            cell?.transform = .identity
        })
        cell = self.cv.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: index + 1, section: 0))
        UIView.animate(withDuration: options.animationDuration, animations: {
            cell?.transform = self.options.transformScale
        })
    }
    else
    {
        var cell = self.cv.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
        UIView.animate(withDuration: options.animationDuration, animations: {
            cell?.transform = .identity
        })

        index -= 1  // Left
        cell = self.cv.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
        UIView.animate(withDuration: options.animationDuration, animations: {
            cell?.transform = self.options.transformScale
        })

        index += 2 // Right
        cell = self.cv.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
        UIView.animate(withDuration: options.animationDuration, animations: {
            cell?.transform = self.options.transformScale
        })
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a separate `UIView` with same frame as `item`, set its content to `UIView` if `item` has image or something, and finally transform/scale `UIView`'s frame to the full screen.

You can then make it disappear with animation or transform it back to identity, as you want. You shouldn't change `CollectionViewCell`'s frame.